# OpenSSH no longer accessible

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 server on an older mac mini. Initially I was using a hard line for networking but after fighting with netplan I finally got wifi working. However, in a very strange turn of events ssh suddenly stopped working altogether. The computer *is* connected as I can see an ip address when running `ifconfig` and I can connect to the network and internet as a whole. When I try to ssh to the machine though I only receive a timeout. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Please edit with output of "cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Comment: I assume you sshd is listening on different IP address.